# Show/hide record from extjs's store

Tags: extjs, charts, grid, store

I got Grid and Chart who shares same store.
Also I got some checkboxes (generated by the records from the store) which are suppose to hide/show records from grid and chart so I think that the best  way do to id is by hiding/showing the record from the store on select/deselect a checkbox...
Is it possible to hide a record from the store when I uncheck specific checkbox and unhide the same record when I check the box ?

Comment: can you share details how grid and chart sharing same store

Comment: There are many ways but I'm doing it that way : http://jsfiddle.net/g2C5j/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should use the [filterBy](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy) method form the store.

```
store.filterBy(function(rec){
    if (/* verify if the checkbox for this record is checked*/){
     return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }
})
```